# How to remove write protection from USB stick

Tags: usb-flash-drive, virus, cmd.exe

I have followed up the below process in cmd:

```
DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.
```

Even if I do that it displays `Read-only:yes:`

```
DISKPART> attributes disk Current Read-only State : Yes Read-only :yes Boot Disk : No Pagefile Disk : No Hibernation File Disk : No Crashdump Disk : No Clustered Disk : No

DISKPART>
```

How can I remove the write protection from this USB flash drive? I have tried several things I found on the Internet.

I guess it happened because of a virus infection.

Comment: Don't know that this will have been caused by a virus. Do you *know* you had one? I had a 32GB memory stick that went read-only due to a partial failure of the stick. Remember that they are not especially reliable.

Comment: I heard that when USB drives full it automatically takes Write protection.I guess it cause of a virus because it doesn't allow me to delete some files.I have used this drive as a bootable one and it contains windows 8 setup.I can't delete it

Comment: When a flash drive runs out of spare blocks to replace failed blocks, it goes into read-only mode.  This provides a way to off-load your contents before the drive fails completely.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...for windows only:

Click start, then run `regedit` and go to directory `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Currentcontrolset\control\StorageDevicePolicies`

(If you can't find `StorageDevicePolicies` under the control folder then create it:

1. Right-click the `control` folder
2. Select `new`, then click `key` and rename the `new key #1` folder into `StorageDevicePolicies`
3. Right-click the `StorageDevicePolicies` folder and select `new DWORD(32-bit) Value` for a 32-bit Operating System, or `new DWORD(64-bit) Value` for a 64-bit Operating System
4. Rename dword newer folder into `WriteProtect`, then double-click `WriteProtect` and change the value data into 0 with hexadecimal base
5. Close regedit
6. Open my computer and refresh it 5 times without doing anything to your usb, and properly eject your flash drive
7. Plug in your usb again into your computer and format it using exfat instead of fat32

Now, you can use your flash drive again.

Comment: Nope, welcome to nopeland, does not work!